# Moving certain items to the right of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, everyone. Please I'm a newbie in CSS and HTML, and this is literally my first project.

So, I'm trying to build a navigation menu, and I'm trying to move two items("SIGN IN" and "CART") to the right, away from the other items on the navbar. But I can't seem to get them to move. navbar-right doesn't work. I've tried housing them inside a container and giving them a relative position, but then the navbar menu is not responsive when I decrease the size of the screen. Also, for some unknown reason, the glyphicon shopping cart item refuses to be displayed.

in my main.css, this is my code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>Ecommerce</title>
    {% load static %}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'store/styles.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light md-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jumaz</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Home</a>
                </li>
                <div id="formAndButton">
                    <form id="search" method="get" class="d-flex" action="#">
                    <input id="input" class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search products" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning text-light" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!--i intend moving the following items to the right and make them responsive when screen is shrunk-->

                <div class="navbar" id="moveRight">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">SIGN IN</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <!-- glyphicon shopping cart item does not load -->
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>CART</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

{% block body %}

{% endblock body %}

</body>
</html>
```

in my styles.css, i have -

```
#input{
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 9px 4px 9px 40px;
    background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' class='bi bi-search' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat 13px center;

}


#formAndButton{
    margin-left: 100px;

}

/*i tried relative positioning of the items like this, but it isn't responsive when screen is shrunk*/

#moveRight{
    position:relative; left:200px;
}

li { margin-left: 15px }
In my styles.css, I also tried-
#moveRight{
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;}
and also tried,
#moveRight{
grid-column-start: 5; }
```

Comment: @Dimitris Maragkos thanks. Your answer helped with the aligning problem. But how do I make the navigation items to still be visible when screen size is reduced? given the current code, when I decrease screen size, the search button disappears from view even when you press the toggle button to reveal collapsed items.

Comment: For the icon, simply use the font-awesome shopping cart icon `<i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">` should not be nested inside `<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">`. They should be next to each other.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Home</a>
        </li>
        <div id="formAndButton">
            <form id="search" method="get" class="d-flex" action="#">
                <input id="input" class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search products" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-warning text-light" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">SIGN IN</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i>CART</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For the icon use the font-awesome shopping cart icon `<i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i>`.